# SSIS ScriptTask hangs on Debug

Tags: ssis

New to SSIS packages. I am working with an SSIS Package in Visual Studio 2013 after installing SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

When I edit the ScriptTask, it opens Visual Studio 2012. I place a breakpoint on the line of code I want to hit in the Main() method. The ScriptTask's EntryPoint is also set to Main().

When I debug the SSIS package, it gets to the ScriptTask and opens Visual Studio 2012 and that's it. It never hits my breakpoint. It just hangs. Sometimes I get a modal window that says something about the window will close when the debugging has stopped. This window has a single button on it that says "Stop Debugging".

Does anyone know what is happening here? How can I get it to hit the breakpoint, so I can debug my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to have the debugger hit your breakpoint, you should change your SSIS Project's "Run64BitRuntime" propery's value from its default True to False.

But that's not enough. Because your "Script Task" is still compiled as 64bit. You should edit your Script Task with "Edit Script" and save it again. This will help your script task code to be compiled as 32bit.

Credits:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farukcelik/archive/2010/03/17/why-the-breakpoints-that-i-set-in-my-script-task-not-script-component-in-the-data-flow-never-hits.aspx